# Marcar elemento html

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho meus elementos  em um texto.

```
<h2> Titulo </h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
<h2> OUTRO TITULO </h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
<h2> OUTRO TITULO </h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
```

e eu gostaria de marcar os elementos h2 em memória, sei lá, para depois eu criar um sumário com eles, usando `<li>` e `counter` no CSS.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Uma forma de se fazer isso envolve usar jQuery. Uma resposta com jQuery seria aceitável no seu caso?

Comment: Posso ter entendido mal, mas porque não dás uma classe de CSS aos teus elementos, tipo: `<h2 class="sumario">texto</h2>` ? Assim ficam marcados e podes aceder aos mesmos através da classe `.sumario`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo, sem JQuery, em que os elementos H2 são armazenados num array, quando pressionados, e apresentados numa lista quando o botão é pressionado.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L4Cs/)

```
var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    headers[i].onclick = armazena;
}

var titulos = [];

function armazena() {
    titulos.push(this);
}

function mostra() {
    var lista = document.getElementById('lista');
    lista.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < titulos.length; i++) {
        var el = document.createElement('li');
        el.innerHTML = titulos[i].innerHTML;
        lista.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```

Comment: era bem isso que eu queria :D

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa marcar os títulos.

Basta montar sua lista em um script. Segue código testado:

```
var headings = Sizzle('h2');

for( var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++ ) {
    document.write('<ul>');
    document.write('<li>' + headings[i].innerHTML + '</li>');
    document.write('</ul>');
}
```

O código procura todas as tags 'h2' do seu código. Dê uma olhada no link abaixo:

> [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/77bMG/17/)

Comment: Nem precisa do Sizzle, pode usar `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: Ou `document.getElementsByTagName`, caso preze pela compatibilidade.

Comment: Acho que me expressei mal, eu gostaria que ao clicar em cima do H2 onClick, ele armazene na memória, para se eu tiver um botão, ele gerar o sumário pra mim...

Comment: A ideia seria, ter N(vários) h2, e apenas os que eu selecionar guardar em memória para depois gerar uma lista com conteudo dos mesmos

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser armazenar num array pra trabalhar com eles dinamicamente, pode usar isso:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var data = [];
    $('h2').each(function(){
        data.push($(this));
    })
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmendonca/2ERKj/)

Comment: No exemplo postado, percebi que os títulos só aparecem quando você chama a `DIV` com o `id = Lista`. Não acho que seja o objetivo da pergunta.

Comment: É só um exemplo pra mostrar que o JS armazenou os <h2> e como ele pode utilizá-los, umas vez que estão na memória do js.